# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') error

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to pass a route from one component to another, and I'm getting this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

I don't know why I'm getting this error.

this is my useRouting

```
const useRouting = () => {
    const { primaryRole } = useAuth();
    const { asapUser } = useAsapContext();
    const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState(null);

    const routesMetadataForRole = useMemo(() => getRoutesForRole(primaryRole), [primaryRole]);

    const routes = useMemo(() => routesPerRole(routesMetadataForRole), [routesMetadataForRole]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (primaryRole === 'asap-dept-member') {
            apiService.ApplicationService.getMemberApplication(asapUser.id).then(response => {
                const application = response.find(application => application.applicant.user.id === asapUser?.id);
                if (application !== null) {
                    setInitialRoute(routesMetadataForRole[2]?.path.replace(':id', application?.id));
                } else {
                    setInitialRoute(routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path);
                }
            });
        } else {
            setInitialRoute(routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path);
        }
    }, [primaryRole, routesMetadataForRole, asapUser.id]);

    return { routes, routesMetadataForRole, initialRoute };
};
```

and this is my BaseLayoutRoutes

```
const BaseLayoutRoutes = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { routes, initialRoute } = useRouting();
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.pathname === '/' && routes && routes.length > 0) {
            navigate(initialRoute, { replace: true });
        }
    }, [initialRoute, navigate, location.pathname, routes]);

    return <Routes>{routes}</Routes>;
};
```

and finally an error I'm getting from initialRoute

[image]

stacktrace

[image]

Comment: The type error about the `pathname` doesn't match the later screen capture. The issue in the image is that `initialRoute` is typeless and isn't assignable to the `To` type that the `navigate` function uses. What is the `initialRoute` value you are passing? Can you double check what the type error is with `pathname` and provide *that* error's error message and code stacktrace?

Comment: hey, Drew thanks a lot for your comment! I've just edited my post and added stack trace, thanks again I appreciate it!

Comment: What are the values of `routesMetadataForRole[2]?.path` and `routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path` that the `initialRoute` state is updated to? The error is saying `initialRoute` is undefined. It seems one of those Optional Chaining operators is hitting a null|undefined value and returning early. It seems you should add a fallback value for this. Is there a route you could navigate to safely, like `"/"`?

Comment: so the idea is to navigate based on if there is an application for this specific user and if there is an application navigate to application/view/:id and if not navigate to the new-application route. routesMetadataForRole[2]?.path is for view and routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path is for new-application. everywhere I'm trying to navigate I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error and stacktrace is informing you that the `initialRoute` value that is passed to the `navigate` function is undefined.

Only issue the redirect if the `initialRoute` value exists.

```
const BaseLayoutRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { routes, initialRoute } = useRouting();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === '/' && routes?.length && initialRoute) {
      navigate(initialRoute, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [initialRoute, navigate, location.pathname, routes]);

  return <Routes>{routes}</Routes>;
};
```